# javascript Using setInterval inside a while loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

I'm developing a mini game where you have to click on the right target. I have a set of div with different id's numbered from 1 to 9. Every 3 seconds the target changes. To select the target I've done a function that randomly selects a targets until the user hits the correct one. This is the code I have made far now:

```
let game;
let victory = false;
let target;


const win = () => {
    victory = true;
    return alert('Has ganado');
}


const setTarget = () => {

    console.log("funcion setTarget");
    target = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

    // Añadimos la classe red
    document.getElementById(target).classList.add("target");

    // Al target actual le ponemos un eventlistener
    document.getElementById(target).addEventListener('click', win);

    return target;

}



// Al target anterior hay que eliminarle la classe red y quitarle el eventlistener
const removeTarget = () => {


    // Eliminamos la classe red
    document.getElementById(target).classList.remove("target");

    // Al target anterior le borro la classe "target"
    document.getElementById(target).removeEventListener('click', win);

    return target;

}


const startGame = () => {


    while (victory) {

        console.log("Entramos en el while");

        setTarget(); // Aplicamos estilo al target y le aplicamos event listener

        setTimeout(() => removeTarget, 30000); // Esperamos 3 segundos y eliminamos el target

    }

    return true;

}



// Ejecuta la función que hace todo el juego
startGame();
```

Inside the function startGame I need to execute the function setTarget() and then wait 3 seconds before execute removeTarget this should be happening until the user hits the correct element. When the users click the correct element the victory changes to true and the loops exits. Now when I load the page it doesnt waits at all and it's going so fast that I can't see the div's changing the color.

This is the html for if can be usefull:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="1"></div>
            <div id="2"></div>
            <div id="3"></div>
          </div>
           
          <div>
            <div id="4"></div>
            <div id="5"></div>
            <div id="6"></div>
          </div>
           
          <div>
            <div id="7"></div>
            <div id="8"></div>
            <div id="9"></div>
          </div>


        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
div>div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
 
  .target {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

Comment: the while loop keeps the javascript engine busy, never letting any code outside of the loop from executing, including the callback to setTimeout ... therefore `victory` can never change

Comment: but, in your case, the while loop would never start - so no code in there will ever run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code Changes:

Don't use a `while`, that is what the interval is for:

```
const startGame = () => {
    setTarget();
    window.my_interval = setInterval(adjustTarget, 30*1000);
}
```

And then once the user wins, clear the interval:

```
const win = () => {
    clearInterval(window.my_interval);
    removeTarget();
    alert('Has ganado');
}
```

You'll need an interim method that resets the target. So declare another function that does this for you, like:

```
function adjustTarget(){
    removeTarget();
    setTarget();
}
```

## Summary of things to learn:

- **First**: `victory` is `false` so your `while` loop never enters.
- **Second**: even if `victory` were true, you'd lock-up your runtime and get `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. The `while` loop does't wait on the `setTimeout()` so it would set thousands/millions/billions of timeouts.
- **Third**: You don't need to declare an anonymous function that then return the reference to `removeTarget`. Just pass the `removeTarget` function reference into `setTimeout()` directly.
- **Fourth**: Your starting value for `victory` at the time you invoke `startGame()` will always be `false`. So you don't need to check it when you start the game.
- **Fifth**: Consider placing all your code inside a `class` for easier variable, state, and scope management.
- **Sixth**: You don't even need a variable for `victory`, it's implied when a user clicks the 'winning' target.
- **Seventh**: You're not using the `return` values of any of your methods. Thus, you shouldn't even use a return statement.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Already made this changes and works fine. I will work again all this concepts you mentioned above I see now that I didn't understand it completely :(

Comment:  We're always here to help. 

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, I have updated the few lines in JavaScript, rest remains the same

```
const win = () => {
victory = true;
clearInterval(startit);
return alert('Has ganado');
}

const startGame = () => {
    console.log("Entramos en el while");
    removeTarget(); // Esperamos 3 segundos y eliminamos el target
    setTarget(); // Aplicamos estilo al target y le aplicamos event listener
}

var startit = setInterval(startGame, 3000);
enter code here
```